# Adding images to a div and making them "active"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am just learning jQuery and have tried to solve this problem multiple ways, too many to list, with no success.  Please help!

Also I can't figure out how to add an image to this question, so pick a favorite cat image and modify the code to reflect its name.  (sorry)

**Instructions:**

1. load the html code and the image into the same directory
2. display the simple.html in your browser (I am using Chrome)
3. click on the image - it gets big
4. click on the big image - it gets small
5. click on the "add images" button - a new image appears
6. click on the first image - it gets big and hides the second image
7. click on the big image - it gets small and the second image is also displayed
8. click on the second image - nothing happens, I want it to get big (and return to small upon a second click)

**CODE :**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>simple demo</title>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- DOM follows-->
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
       <div id="button">Add images</button></div>
       <div class="image_set" id="images">
          <img class="floating-box" src="test_image.jpg">
          <img class="floating-box" src="test_image.jpg">
       </div>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- end of DOM -->
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
       <script>
             $(".floating-box").click(function(){
                if(typeof floatingBoxMode == "undefined"){
                   floatingBoxMode = "full";
                }
                if (floatingBoxMode == "full"){
                   // need to set image css to fullsize
                   $(this).css("width", "auto");
                   $(this).css("height", "auto");
                   $(".floating-box").hide ();
                   $(this).show ();
                   floatingBoxMode = "single";
                }else{
                   // need to set css to thumbnail
                   $(this).css("width", "auto");
                   $(this).css("height", "150px");
                   $(this).show ();
                   $(".floating-box").show ();
                   floatingBoxMode = "full";
                };
             });
             $("#button").click (function () {
                var s = '<img class="floating-box" src="test_image.jpg">';
                $("#images").append (s);
             });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .floating-box {
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid #8AC007;  
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 80%;
    }
    .floating-box-fullsize {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid #8AC007;  
    }
    .image_set{
    margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
    margin-top: 0;
    }
    </style>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to delegate click event: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write

```
$('.image_set').on('click','.floating-box',function(){
```

instead of

```
$(".floating-box").click(function(){
```

**Dynamically added elements** needs `event delegation` for their events to get fired

Here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t6ykw7z5/)**

Comment: This is simple and to the point! Thanks.  I love stackoverflow